# Android Fragment: Progressbar shows up, rotating and doesn't hide

Tags: android, android-fragments

I started learning programming Android Apps some days ago and I always managed to find an answer by watching youtube videos or searching on this site here. But the following problem I couldn't even find.

In the class `Navigation`I'm starting/loading a fragment (`Fragement_trupp1`). And it works great but I'm always having a rotating progressbar in the background (look at the image), so behind the text and buttons (but you still can see it...). The thing I'm wondering about is that I never created this progressbar and its only this one Activity I have this problem.

**Navigation.java**

```
public class Navigation extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    ActionBar myActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    myActionBar.setTitle("trupp I");


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    Fragement_trupp1 fragment = new Fragement_trupp1();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.id_fragment_navigation, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_navigation, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}}
```

**activity_navigation.xml**

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/id_fragment_navigation"
        android:name="android.support.v4.app.ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_trupp1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[progressbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZDL2.jpg)

*Image of the progressbar rotating. Need 10 reputations to post it directly :O*

The error must have something to do with calling the fragment in `Navigation.java`because if I remove this part and the Fragement-part in the xml-file I dont have the problem. And btw I'm using API lvl 24!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this layout instead

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/id_fragment_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

you add fragment dynamically and no need to declare fragment in the layout.
please choose just one of the approach.

hope it helps